# Confused to determine the covariance two insurance payments

Tags: probability, covariance

> Let remaining life of couple of husband and wife is independent and
> uniformly distributed over $[0,40]$.  The insurance company offers 2
> products for married couples, namely the first payment when the
> husband dies and the second when the husband and wife die. Calculate
> the covariance of the two payments.

I have tried as below.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be remaining life of husband and wife respectively, so we have
$$
f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{1}{1600}& 0\leq x\leq 1, 0\leq y\leq 1\\
0&\text {otherwise}
\end{cases}.
$$

Now I confused to determine the mathematics language of "the covariance of the two payments". Is it right we are asked to compute $\operatorname{cov}(40-X,40-X-Y)$?